# ElasticSearch - set ingest cluster to push documents to two separate data clusters?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is this possible?

ElasticSearch version 6.4.2.

Right now we have a 3-node ElasticSearch Ingest cluster which prepares documents and pushes them to our 3-node data cluster.  We need to have the ingest cluster push the documents to two different 3-node clusters residing at two different IP addresses (both clusters are identical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is by leveraging [cross-cluster replication](https://www.elastic.co/blog/cross-datacenter-replication-with-elasticsearch-cross-cluster-replication) (CCR).

CCR allows you to instruct a "slave" data center to follow a "master" one and get hold of all the master data in near real-time.

**UPDATE:**

Since your ES version doesn't support CCR yet, you have two main options: your microservice can send the data

1. to both ES clusters at the same time
2. to a Logstash endpoint that will then relay the data to both clusters (using two `elasticsearch` output)

Comment: Hi Val, it's great to see you here with your great ES help as always.  I guess it would have been beneficial for me to put that we are on ES version 6.4.2 at the moment.  Looks like CCR was introduced in version 6.7.  Certainly makes for a good reason to need to upgrade, but right now we simply don't have time or resources to do so.  I am editing my post to indicate which version we are on.  Let me know how this kind of requirement was achieved in version prior to 6.7

Comment: How do you send your data to the ES cluster?

Comment: We send it to ES from our SQL Server database using microservices written in .Net.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer - related to #1 suggestion - right now what we do is our microservice pushes the data to the ES ingest cluster which then prepares the data further, and then pushes it to the Data cluster which is what is used for search.  I am a little confused on your answer #1 - since our microservice is step 1, ingest cluster is step 2 and data cluster is step 3 - how can we do step 1 to step 3a/3b (two different data clusters) without bypassing step 2?  We need step 2 to prep the data for both data clusters.

Comment: is your ingest cluster an ES cluster with only ingest nodes or something completely different? and how do you instruct that cluster to forward data to the data cluster?

Comment: The ingest cluster is only an ingest cluster.  As far as I can tell, the parameter in elasticsearch.yml called discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts contains the 3 IP addresses of the machines on our data cluster.  Could it be as simple as just adding additional IP addresses there?  I must admit I'm not much more well-versed than that on this topic - I've inherited this solution and am still trying to understand.

Comment: What I don't get is how the ingest node from the ingest cluster forwards the documents to the data nodes in another data cluster? This routing is usually something internal to an ES cluster, not something you define externally. My guess is that all those nodes are in one and the same ES cluster, not two separate clusters

Comment: Perhaps then it's my lack of understanding that's the problem.  But as far as I can see, they are two separate clusters, 3 nodes each.  We have them set up in Azure as two completely separate VM Availability sets.  Are you familiar with the parameter I mentioned in my last comment?

Comment: If the ingest nodes have the IPs of the data nodes in their config, it means they are all part of the same cluster, which makes more sense to me. whether in the same VM or not, makes no difference as long as they are reachable.

Comment: I see.  Well the 2nd data cluster does not have an ingest cluster.  This is why I was trying to send the data out of the one ingest cluster to the two data clusters.  The 2nd data cluster is located in a different datacenter, FYI.

Comment: Yeah, the second data cluster is probably completely separate, indeed. then what you can simply do is to add ingest nodes to your second cluster and then the two options I listed are still valid.

Comment: Hi Val.  I've discussed with my team and it seems creating ingest cluster for the 2nd setup is needed.  Thanks for the guidance.